# Updating  SQL Server 2008 records w/spatial data types via Massive ORM (ExecuteNonQuery), UdtTypeName error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, massive

I'm trying to use Massive "dynamic ORM" by Rob Conery to query my DB (working GREAT so far). Ran into a problem when I added a Geography field to my tables.

**Here's the error:**
 `UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters`

**Update (14Apr2011):** The ADO method that is throwing the exception is `.ExecuteNonQuery();` Here's the method from Massive.cs that throws the exception:

```
    public virtual int Execute(IEnumerable<DbCommand> commands) {
        var result = 0;
        using (var conn = OpenConnection()) {
            using (var tx = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
                foreach (var cmd in commands) {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Transaction = tx;
                    result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The specific line that throws it is: `result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

**Here's the important bits of the table:**

- PlaceId - bigint PK
- Name - nvarchar
- GeoLocation (Geography type - as a Point)
- ...

It's hard to find any others out there using Massive, but I did report the error on [Massive's GitHub Issues tab](https://github.com/robconery/massive/issues). You can view the [source code for Massive here](https://github.com/robconery/massive/blob/master/Massive.cs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure how best to integrate this into Massive, but basically you need to do exactly what the error says:

```
yourGeographyParam.UdtTypeName = "Geography";
```

Basically SQL Server needs you to explicitly name the UdtTypeName for the "weird" parameters:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2008/06/11/udttypename-and-net-data-types-in-sql.aspx