# Dynamic adding arguments to dapper query

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I trying to dynamically send a list of arguments to be executed by query. Currently I have a spatial query

```
SELECT top(0 + 30) ListingView.*, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY ListingView.BedroomsTotal ASC) AS RowNum
FROM ListingView 

WHERE ListingView.MLSKey = 'nsmls' AND ListingView.Ficoscore = '760-850' AND       ListingView.LifeStyle = 'couple-no-kids' AND ListingView.LoanType = '30YrFixed'     AND ListingView.StandardStatus IN 
('active', 'pending') AND ListingView.ListPrice >1 AND     ListingView.PropertyType = 'SF' AND     (ListingView.GeoLocation.STIntersects(@GeoLocation0) = 1 OR 
ListingView.GeoLocation.STIntersects(@GeoLocation1) = 1
```

In this spatial query, geolocation0 and geolocation1 are hardcoded arguments. I may have multiple geolocation locations that I need to add in query.

My current dapper arguments look like this:

```
 var args = new
 {
 @LivingAreaMin = predicates.GetLivingAreaSqftMin(),
 @LivingAreaMax = predicates.GetLivingAreaSqftMax(),
 @GeoLocation0 = ((lstLocationPolygon != null && lstLocationPolygon.Count >   0) ? SqlGeometry.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(new SqlString(
     string.Format("POLYGON(({0}))", lstLocationPolygon[0]))), 0) : null),

 @GeoLocation1 = ((lstLocationPolygon != null && lstLocationPolygon.Count >   1) ? SqlGeometry.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(new SqlString(
 string.Format("POLYGON(({0}))", lstLocationPolygon[1]))), 0) : null),

 @GeoLocation2 = ((lstLocationPolygon != null && lstLocationPolygon.Count > 2) ? SqlGeometry.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(new SqlString(
 string.Format("POLYGON(({0}))", lstLocationPolygon[2]))), 0) : null),
}
```

In this it is possible that GeoLocation parameter can be more than 3 or less than 3, so I need to add them dynamically. I have used [How to create arguments for a Dapper query dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481678/how-to-create-arguments-for-a-dapper-query-dynamically/9481752#9481752) link for solution.

When I tried with DynamicParameters() but give me following error.

> Additional information: UdtTypeName property must be set only for UDT parameters.

I have also tried with IEnumerable> and Dictionary but it gives me following error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@xyz", even if I declare all variables correctly.

Can you point me correct direction.

Comment: Iterate over the lstlocationPolygon?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall Yes.

Comment: I have same problem. @ThomasLindvall could you please explain how by iterating I can assign to the *args* object?

Comment: UDT problem might be solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644466/updating-sql-server-2008-records-w-spatial-data-types-via-massive-orm-executen I would add all the geoLoc to a collection object and add it as a @locations to my args object and then add "in @locations" to my SQLquery

Comment: @ThomasLindvall How can I use UdtTypeName property with dapper argument?

Comment: @Nirmal what version are you using of dapper?

Comment: 1.32 and above should actually support it, otherwise look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690565/using-dapper-with-sql-spatial-types-as-a-parameter